# How can you increase timeout in Linq2Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I'm doing a basic select against a view.  Unfortunately the result can be slow and I'm getting timeout errors intermittently.  How can I increase the timeout?

Using .NET 3.5, Sql Server 2000, Linq2Entities

I'm using the very basic query `List<MyData> result = db.MyData.Where(x.Attribute == search).ToList();`

Fixing the query so that it's faster on the DB side is not an option here.

Exact Error:  "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Update: I'd prefer to just change it for this one query.

Comment: Um, why not fix the query, instead? You're probably missing an index.

Comment: "Fixing the query so that it's faster on the DB side is not an option here." - That's why I put this line in there.  That's not possible in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the timeout in your [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords).

**Edit (new):**
It turns out that there are two different timeout concepts. The connection timeout is used to determine wether or not a connection can be established. The `CommandTimeout` property on the object context controls timeout for commands. So just set that to a high value, and it should not influence the short-running queries in any way.

Comment: Is that the only way?  I'd prefer to just change it for this one query.  In other queries, I'd rather have it timeout sooner, since they are very fast and a longer run would mean a failure to connect.

Comment: @Russell Steen: I have updated my answer with another option.

Comment: Example: `(MyDbContextSubclass as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 300;`

Comment: Setting CommandTimeout to 0 means it will wait indefinitely for the command to complete.